# Developing a Group Chat Application

Tags: apache-kafka, chat

Can Kafka be used to create a Group Chat Application. If yes, what resources would I need and what would I need to learn?

Comment: Can you? Yes... Would it be overkill?... Most likely.

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you could try explaining how you would see Kafka being used in your ideal scenario.

Answer (score 0):

[Producer API](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerapi) and [Consumer API](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#comsumerapi) should be enough to start with. No need to go into ops territory for a POC - default deployment should work out of the box.